# Import javax.vecmath

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, vecmath

I would like to use `javax.vecmath` in my Java program but unfortunately it says:

> The import javax.vecmath cannot be resolved

Should I add the jar by myself in the project? Where can I find that jar file? I'm on Ubuntu/Eclipse Galileo.

Comment: you should mark an answer that has worked for you as accepted.

Answer (score 15):

On Ubuntu you can `apt-get install libvecmath-java`. On other systems do what Petar Minchev suggests, or search on Google for something like "java vecmath", which turns up [https://vecmath.dev.java.net/](http://java.net/projects/vecmath/), and then go to their [downloads page](http://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html).

Comment: How do you get the jar aded to the classpath once you install that?

Comment: @AJMansfield run `dpkg -L libvecmath-java` to see where the jar is. For me it's `/usr/share/java/vecmath-1.5.2.jar`. Then just add that jar to your classpath however you normally would (`CLASSPATH` environment variable, IDE settings, `-cp` or `-classpath` command line switch, etc.)

Answer (score 10):

Instead of trying to obtain the file through some OS-dependent package,
it would be better to use a dependency manager, for example Maven or Gradle.
Using Maven, you could add this dependency to the `pom.xml` file of your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.vecmath</groupId>
    <artifactId>vecmath</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

See the latest version of the package on [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.vecmath/vecmath/).

---

As the top-voted answer suggests, you can get the jar in Ubuntu with:

```
apt-get install libvecmath-java
```

And then you can find the location of the jar file with:

```
dpkg -L libvecmath-java | grep jar$
```

Which should output something like:

```
/usr/share/java/vecmath-1.5.2.jar
/usr/share/java/vecmath.jar
```

It's really just one jar, the file without version is a symbolic link to the other.

To add a jar to the build path in Eclipse (in a non-Maven project):

1. Right-click on the project
2. Select **Build Path / Add External Archives...**
3. Browse to the jar file and select it

---

In other operating systems you can download the jar file directly from Maven Central:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.vecmath/vecmath/

Answer (score 3):

Search for the `vecmath` file, you may find it in `/usr/share/java`.

Copy the contents of this folder to `/jdk_installation_folder/jre/lib/ext`.

For me, it is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext`.

To copy you can use either the `cp`-command or change the `ext` folder permission to `777` using `chmod`.

```
$ chmod 777 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext
```

Then copy all the files in file explorer.

```
$ chmod 755 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext
```

If you do did not find the `vecmath.jar` file, then download and install it.

```
apt-get install libvecmath-java
```

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion#1:

**libvecmath-java** software package provides javax.vecmath vector math package, you can install in your `Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus)` by running the commands given below on the terminal,

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libvecmath-java
```

libvecmath-java is installed in your system.

Make ensure the libvecmath-java package were installed using the commands given below,

```
$ sudo dpkg-query -l | grep libvecmath-java *
```

You will get with libvecmath-java package name, version, architecture and description in a table.

**Resource Link:** http://thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus/libvecmath-java

### Suggestion#2:

Open a terminal and install the Java 3D API. This api is also includes vecmath.jar.

```
sudo apt-get install libjava3d-java
```

**Resource Link:**

1. https://askubuntu.com/a/626128
2. https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/libjava3d-java

### Suggestion#3:

You can also download the zip, binary or exe from the following oracle link:

1. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#java3d-1.5.1-oth-JPR

### Suggestion#4:

In eclipse, step by step installation procedure with pictures, is given in the following link:

1. https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs324e/handouts/setUpJava3dEclipse.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you are having this issue in an Android project in Android Studio, I had a similar problem and added the following to my dependencies inside of app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'javax.vecmath:vecmath:1.5.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Download](https://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html)(updated) the jar and add it to the classpath. In the linked page it is in the "zip binaries", and there in `j3d-jre.zip`'s lib dir.

Comment: The Download link doesn't work! However I found the updated [Download](https://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html) link! (simply remove the .dev)